Log-likelihood calculation for unigrams
I am calculating the log-likelihood for each unigram that I generated by using the CountVectorizer to see each unigram's importance. However, I got all the positive value after calculating the log-likelihood. I just want to know am I doing right? I use the log-likelihood for the feature selection for unigrams.
Here is the code for calculating log-likelihood:
# Feature Selection Log-Likelihood function
def cal_LogLikelihood(features_value):
  n = len(features_value)
  mean = np.mean(features_value)
  var = np.var(features_value)
  print(var)
  log_likelihood = -n * np.log(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) - (n / 2) * np.log(var) - (1 / (2 * var)) * np.sum((features_value - mean) ** 2)
  return log_likelihood

